# add categorical xticklabels at specified position

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable, nodes-near-coords

I am trying to make a bar chart for categorical data, where each category has a score and the number of items in a category is represented by the width of the bar. Based on [Bar chart from CSV file with adjustable bar width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152243/bar-chart-from-csv-file-with-adjustable-bar-width) I tried to add the category labels on the x axis with `xticklabels from table`:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
name  height width
foo   1      884
bar   2      5768
baz   3      835
qux   7      2661
quux  10     492
corge 11     1349
clyde 11     0
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xticklabels from table={data.csv}{name},
typeset ticklabels with strut
]
\addplot [ybar interval, fill=yellow] table [
        create on use/xaccum/.style={
            create col/expr=\pgfmathaccuma+\prevrow{width}
        },
        x=xaccum, y=height
    ] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This solution however does not align the xticklabels to the bars:

[image]

I was thinking about adding a `extra description` nodes or `extra x tick`, or using an extra loop after plotting to add nodes based on the new 'xaccum' column, but I'm not sure how to implement something like that.

Bonus question: how to remove the 10e4?

Other solutions (with or without pgfplots) are also welcome. In principle I can precompute or modify the data if needed (in LaTeX or otherwise). An example would be to (automatically) add zero-height unlabeled rows before and after narrow bars to prevent label overlap.

Comment: add `xtick=data` to the `axis` options to "align" the `xticklabels` (at the beginning of the bar, but then the labels will overlap)

Comment: @StefanPinnow that is already much better than what I had, thanks! In the end I made the graph with gnuplot, which allows to explicitly set the x position, width and label of each bar (and also a global label offset).

Answer (score 2):

This is not a perfect solution, but hopefully a good start if you want to keep the bar width showing "something" that is also repeated as a node.

For details please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% PGFPlots v1.15
    \begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
        name  height width
        foo   1      884
        bar   2      5768
        baz   3      835
        qux   7      2661
        quux  10     492
        corge 11     1349
        clyde 11     0
    \end{filecontents}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xticklabels from table={data.csv}{name},
        typeset ticklabels with strut,
        % to align the `xticklabels` properly
        % (although they overlap now)
        xtick=data,
        % to remove the "10^4"
        scaled ticks=false,
        % to add nodes with the `width' value
        nodes near coords,
        point meta=explicit,
    ]
        \addplot [ybar interval, fill=yellow] table [
            create on use/xaccum/.style={
                create col/expr=\pgfmathaccuma+\prevrow{width}
            },
            x=xaccum,
            y=height,
            meta=width,     % <-- also added to display the `width' value
        ] {data.csv};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]